# Send variable to PHP script while getting data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First of all let me tell you all I'm very new to js, jQuery & ajax. But I'm very well with PHP.

I got a jQuery script from the internet:

```
function getMessages (){
        $.get('php/chatGetter.php', function(data){
            $("#msgbox").html(data);
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        getMessages();
    }, 500);
});
```

As you can see it gets data from chatGetter.php page and shows in div whose id is msgbox every 500 millisecond.

I want to send a php variable (`$abc ="something";`) through function getMessages to `chatGetter.php` page every time the `getMessages` function is executed. But I'm not getting how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JS code is in your PHP file do this.

```
function getMessages (someVariable){
        $.get('php/chatGetter.php?abc=' + someVariable, function(data){
            $("#msgbox").html(data);
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){
      var someVariable = '<?php echo($abc);?>';  
      getMessages(someVariable);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: yes js is in php file and variable i want to send is already declared and initiated in php above js

Comment: @ShaaNMalik Then the above code should work, make sure you update the variable names

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in your jQuery code:

```
function getMessages (){
        var something = 'something';
        $.get('php/chatGetter.php?abc=' + something, function(data){
            $("#msgbox").html(data);
        });
    }

 setInterval(function(){  
      getMessages();
 }, 500);
```

And then, in the `chatGetter.php` file, add this on the top:

```
if(isset($_GET['abc'])) {
     // do whatever you wanna do, here...
}
```

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnL5Lsmz/